# OpenCV: How to save images in a big matrix then call them separately?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, matrix

I want to read around 50 video frames using cv::VideoCapture, then call these 50 images one by one to do some other work. For doing this, I tried using resize and some other method, but still couldn't solved it. For instance, I get images from a video like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture myCapture(0);
while(true)
{
    cv::Mat inputFrame;
    myCapture>>inputFrame;
}
```

I want to save the first 50 `inputFrame`, then call them one-by-one later to do some other work. Processing the current frame first and then reading the next frame is not what I want to do. Also, I don't want to write them first into my hard disk then read them. I want a kind of cell that contains image matrix. Is there any solution?

Comment: Actually `Mat inputFrame` is stored as a matrix, you can process it in your loop `while(ture)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<cv::Mat> frames;
cv::Mat inputFrame;

for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
    myCapture>>inputFrame;
    frames.push_back(inputFrame);
}
```

It will fill vector `frames`with the images. You can then access them as you wish. A slight variant on this would be to instantiate this vector and then overwrite consecutive entries rather than using the `push_back` method:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<cv::Mat> frames;
frames.resize(50);
cv::Mat inputFrame;

for(size_t i=0; i<frames.size(); i++){
    myCapture>>inputFrame;
    frames[i] = inputFrame;
}
```

Comment: please edit again, and make it :  frames[i] = inputFrame.clone(); // else they all point to the same memory